Select query from daabase OEM do check metric Tablespaces Space Used events
Is it possible to use a select query to extract information about metric events from the OEM CC 13 database regarding the "Tablespace Full" metric group and the "Tablespaces Space Used (%)" metric? I am interested in warning occurrences for this metric and whether any corrective actions were taken and with what results?
I was checked:
sysman.mgmt$metric_dialy 
sysman.mgmt$metric_error_history 
sysman.mgmt$metric_error_current 

but this information is not there.
